# Unity NullReferenceException Error w/ New Input System

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm pretty new to unity so I'm sorry if this is an easy fix, but I can't figure it out. I'm getting a null error something to do with my playerInputHandler. Could someone point out where I'm going wrong? I would be so grateful.

Error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Mover.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Mover.cs:37)

PlayerInputHandler.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using static UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction;

public class PlayerInputHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerInput playerInput;
    private Mover mover;

    public bool JumpPressed = false;
    public bool JumpPressing = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
        playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
        var movers = FindObjectsOfType<Mover>();
        var index = playerInput.playerIndex;
        mover = movers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetPlayerIndex() == index);
    }
    
    public void OnMove(CallbackContext context)
    {
        if(mover != null)
            mover.SetInputVector(context.ReadValue<Vector2>());
    }

    public void OnJump(CallbackContext context)
    {
        if(mover != null)
        {
            if (context.started)
            {
                JumpPressing = true;
            }
            else if (context.canceled)
            {
                JumpPressed = true;
            }
        }    
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        JumpPressing = false;
        JumpPressed = false;
    }
    
}
```

Mover.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private float MoveSpeed, JumpSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private int playerIndex = 0;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector2 inputVector = Vector2.zero;
    PlayerInputHandler playerInputHandler;
    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        playerInputHandler = GetComponent<PlayerInputHandler>();
    }

    public int GetPlayerIndex()
    {
        return playerIndex;
    }

    public void SetInputVector(Vector2 direction)
    {
        inputVector = direction;
    }

    void Update()
    {

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(inputVector.x, /*inputVector.y*/0, 0) * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(movement);

        if(playerInputHandler.JumpPressed)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector4(0, JumpSpeed), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
        if(playerInputHandler.JumpPressing)
        {
            Debug.Log("Are you going to jump?");
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

playerInputHandler is null. Make sure you have the PlayerInputHandler component on the same object as the Mover. You could also add `Assert.IsNotNull(playerInputHandler);` at the start of the Update() function to help prevent unwanted behavior like this.

Comment: PlayeInputHandler and the Mover are not able to be on the same empty object because the handler goes on the PlayerInput object while the mover goes to the player sprite objects. And putting Assert.IsNotNull(playerInputHandler); at the start of the update throws this error "The name 'Assert' does not exist in the current context [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0103)"

Comment: You need to add `using UnityEngine.Assertions;` to the top of the file

Comment: Then you need to make the reference to PlayerInputHandler public in the Mover class and set it up in the editor

Comment: What am I needing to do in the editor? I set line 14 of mover to public, but I'm still getting the Null error.

Comment: Go on your object with the Mover script on it you should see PlayerInputHandler and a box next to it. Now drag the object with the PlayerInputHandler script in the box.

Comment: The problem is that the object w/ the PlayerInputHandler is loaded into the PlayerInputManager which then generates the PlayerInput clones while the game is running. I don't know how I would be able to place the PlayerInputs in that box as they are only generated while the game runs, Simply placing the PlayerInput prefab does not seem to work.

Comment: If the object is created at runtime you will need to find the object (using tags for example), then look for the component in the object you found.

Comment: How would I go about doing such a thing.